# php mysql query adds quotes in the end

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up a query as such:

```
$query = 'SELECT SGC.sys_id, TBL.semester, SGC.bonus, SGC.exam, SGC.ca FROM SubjectGradeComponent AS SGC, ';
$query .= '(SELECT `sys_id`, `semester` FROM AcademicYearTerm AS AYT, SubjectYearTermLevel AS SYTL WHERE academic_year = "' . $academic_year . '" AND SYTL.subject_id = ' . $subject_id . ' AND SYTL.form_level = ' . $form_level. ' AND SYTL.yearTerm_id = AYT.yearTerm_id) AS TBL ';
$query .= 'WHERE SGC.sys_id = TBL.sys_id;';
```

However when I run the query, `$mysql->query($query);`it returns an empty result with 0 rows. Running the same query on phpmyadmin shows the desired result. I have looked around but do not understand the problem.

`$mysql->error` does not show any error message either

### EDIT:

generated query is like this:

```
SELECT SGC.sys_id, TBL.semester, SGC.bonus, SGC.exam, SGC.ca FROM SubjectGradeComponent AS SGC, (SELECT `sys_id`, `semester` FROM AcademicYearTerm AS AYT, SubjectYearTermLevel AS SYTL WHERE academic_year = "2018-2019" AND SYTL.subject_id = 1 AND SYTL.form_level = 1 AND SYTL.yearTerm_id = AYT.yearTerm_id) AS TBL WHERE SGC.sys_id = TBL.sys_id;""
```

Question is where are the "" from?

Comment: How does the generated query look like?

Comment: add `echo $query;`

Comment: You should take a look at prepared statement and binding param  .. this could resolve you quotes  issue and overall avoid risk for sqlinjection ....  as last you should avoid old  (1992) implicit join sintax based on where and tables  comma separated .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want a `JOIN` query instead.

You should also use prepared statement with placeholders `?` instead of injecting values directly into the query.

```php
$query = "SELECT SGC.sys_id, 
                 AYT.semester, 
                 SGC.bonus, 
                 SGC.exam, 
                 SGC.ca 
          FROM SubjectGradeComponent AS SGC
          JOIN AcademicYearTerm AS AYT
              ON SGC.sys_id = AYT.sys_id
          JOIN SubjectYearTermLevel AS SYTL 
              ON SYTL.yearTerm_id = AYT.yearTerm_id
          WHERE academic_year = ? 
            AND SYTL.subject_id = ? 
            AND SYTL.form_level = ?";
```

Comment: AYT table does not have `sys_id` but has `yearTerm_id` instead